# Eclipse: don't notice Error when import fail Class

Tags: java, eclipse, package, linker-errors

This below image is my eclipse of my two different projects. And each black rectangle is a package in folder src of Eclipse project. As you know, there a different point: The icon of each package is different.

1) first project: package has normal icon. (like java package)

2) second project: OPPS !!! It displays a folder.

[image: My example Image Screen]
And, the problem that I want to tell is: in project 1, when I type something wrong, eclipse has notice errors. For example: I declare:  `Example() example = new Example();` 
But at project 2, Eclipse cannot. That you have seen on my screen:  `Eclipse eclipse = new Eclipse();`
Obvious, when compiled, It failed.

I think that I might do something wrong, and I just a newcomer to Eclipse, and really don't understand much this IDE.
Please help me for my problem.

thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I think, because you have imported "your package" just by move your source. there are two ways (with my knowledge) that might work:
  1) Like Baldrick does.
  2) go to Properties\Java Build Path\Projects: add a project that contain package you want to add. this will make two project a linker. when you compile this project, this will also compile project that you link to.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the second (lower) project doesn't have the source directory set up as a source directory, so it isn't trying to compile it. No compilation, no errors. Update your project settings by right-clicking and adding the source directory to the source paths.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your projects, go to "Properties" and "Java Build Path". In the "source" tab, add your folder `src` to the list of source folders.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've created a New Folder in your project AndroidGame whereas you created New Package in your other project (can't see name).

You should create a new package in your AndroidGame source folder and "Refactor->Move" your source to it.

As an Eclipse newbie question, you should always Create Package (File -> New -> Package) when creating a package. Folders tend to be required for web content, images, resources (say for property files to be added in your target classpath), etc.